# Redirect traffic over interface for specific destination

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I´m new on stackoverflow and couldn´t find an answer for my question so far by searching on Google so I thought you guys could maybe help me.

What I´m currently trying to do is the following: I want to redirect network traffic over a VPN interface (for example: tun0) but only if I want to surf to a specific destination. For example: If I want to watch a video on YouTube the traffic should not get redirected but if I want to watch a video on hulu.com the traffic should get forwarded through the VPN interface. (I´m not an American so without a VPN connection I do not have access to hulus videos.) Is something like that possible with iptables or some other way? Please help.

Thank you in advance for your efforts and I´m sorry if a similar question has already been asked but I couldn´t find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can give a try with the commands [Described Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface). Ask for more if not solved.